# bitwise operator XOR

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, xor

Trying to understand the XOR importance, I found this code:

> Given a set of numbers where all elements occur even number of times except one number, find the odd occurring number

But I can't visualize it.
How does the XOR bitwise operator roll out the odd element?

```
// Function to return the only odd occurring element
int findOdd(int arr[], int n) {
    int res = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res ^= arr[i];
    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 12, 12, 14, 90, 14, 14, 14 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printf("The odd occurring element is %d\n", findOdd(arr, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `The odd occurring element is 90`

Comment: The code doesn't work. 90 isn't odd. Also, the reason it returns 90 is because each other number in the array is duplicated, so XORing res with the number twice just leaves 0, so the only value that has a lasting effect is 90. Since 0 XOR 90 = 90, that's the return value.

Comment: @bace1000 the number of occurrences of 90 is odd

Comment: I understand it as "find the element that's contained odd times".

Comment: Oh, you wanted the occurrences? I apologise at my inability to read English. My explanation still stands, though.

Comment: Yes, the first comment is the answer.

Comment: It works if there is only *one* number occurring an odd number of times.

Comment: You should [learn](https://github.com/aaronryank/finer-points-of-c/tree/master/5) about how the XOR operator works.

Comment: @WeatherVane :  That is true, but the comment in the first line makes that clear(ish) that that is the intended behaviour.

Comment: Understanding the importance of XOR and understanding this code are two different things.  This code does nothing of importance or much use, whereas XOR is very useful.

Comment: @Clifford perhaps then your comment was even less useful than mine, which had a valid point.

Comment: @WeatherVane : My apologies, I thought you were suggesting that the code did not work rather than actually clarifying its behaviour.  I note that you do state "It works if..." which I misread as "It *only* works if..." - my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I read it you are really asking two questions:

1. What is the importance of XOR?
2. How does XOR help find the odd occurrence of a number in a series?

In order to understand question (2), one must understand question (1). Understanding question (1) requires an adequate introduction to the XOR logic and the properties it has.

**What is the importance of XOR?**

---

Definition: The output of an XOR operation is TRUE if and only if the number of TRUE inputs are *odd*. Commonly referred to as "one or the other, but not both"

This is captured by the following truth table:
[XOR Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuFxv.jpg)

Using the truth table it is trivial to derive the following properties:

- **A ^ 0 = A**                             (The output follows the  variable input)
- **A ^ 1 = A'**                           (The output is the negation of the variable input)
- **A ^ A = 0**                             (The output is always zero since both inputs are equal)
- **(A ^ B) ^ C = A ^ (B ^ C)** (Associative Property)
- **A ^ B = B ^ A**                    (Communative Property)

Now on to the importance of XOR, i.e., how these properties allow folks to make useful things. The first computing layer to note is the hardware layer. XOR gates are physical devices that have utility in many fundamental logic circuits, that fundamental utility being "odd occurrence detection". Some notable applications:

- Half-Adders: The truth table for a half-adders SUM output is identical to the XOR gate. (Throw an AND gate in for the carry bit). Same thing for the Full-Adder, using XOR gates for the fundamental summation with some additional supporting gates.
- Inverters: Using one input as a control and the other as the "input", the xor gate can be used to invert the input signal. The control bit can be used to pass the input through as well, acting as a buffer. In software, you use these circuits to toggle bits/bytes from one state to the other. Val = Val ^ 1 (Recall the second property above).
- Comparators: The output of an XOR gate is 1 when the inputs are different, 0 when they are the same. This is the driving logic for the half-adder.

In addition to these circuits we can, at a hardware level, use XOR to check byte parity for Error Detection and Correction (EDAC) operations, swap register values (without a temp variable!), and recover corrupted/lost data from hard drives in a RAID system.

However, software junkies don't care about these circuits, they want to live in the land of abstractions that provide an easy way to use this hardware in a human intuitive way. Let there be code.

---

**How does XOR help find the odd occurrence of a number in a series?**

Even though the first comment to your question indicates the poster didn't understand your question, they inadvertently answered the question correctly, but I will explain further.

Let's break down what your findOdd() function is actually doing. The for loop is literally performing the following calculation:

Result = 0 ^ 12 ^ 12 ^ 14 ^ 90 ^ 14 ^ 14 ^ 14

Recall that XOR is communative, so after a little re-ordering the calculation becomes:

Result = 0 ^ 12 ^ 12 ^ 14 ^ 14 ^ 14 ^ 14 ^ 90

Using the property A ^ A = 0 and associativity, the XOR of 12 and 12 drops to 0 as does the XOR of the 14's, leaving:

Result = 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 90 = 0 ^ 90 = 90

In effect, the XOR forces even occurrences to become zero and A ^ 0 = A. Hope this verbose description of XOR was helpful in visualizing what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Binary XOR is the **exclusive or** operation, performed one bit at a time. It is equivalent to subtraction, modulo 2.

Here is the truth table for XOR:

```
a   b   a^b
1   0    1
1   1    0
0   0    0
0   1    1
```

As you can see, XOR sets a bit to 1 (true) when EITHER of the input bits is 1, but not both.

Now, consider this: what is 1 xor 1? From the truth table, you know it's zero.

And what is 1 xor 1 xor 1? Well, you know 1^1==0, so that leaves 0^1, which is 1.

So you have that xor'ing a 1 bit an even number of times will produce a zero, and an odd number of times will produce a 1.

Thus, if we take `a ^ a ^ a`, for some value of a, we get a result where all the 1 bits in the binary representation of a are set. (Which is to say, we get back 'a'.)

Whereas if we take `a ^ a ^ a ^ a`, for some value of a, we get a result where all the 1 bits in the binary representation of a are 0. (Which is to say, we get back 0.)

The one exception to this, of course, is 0. The binary representation for 0 has no set bits in it, so this approach will not indicate if the number of 0's was even or odd.

Comment: It is true that you cannot determine the parity of the number of appearances of zero simply by XORing all those appearances together, but if, as in the question, you have an array in which there is exactly one value that appears an odd number of times, then you can identify that value via the OP's code even if it is 0.

Comment: That's true. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

XOR means exclusive or, for each bit in the operands, the resulting bit is `1` if either corresponding bit of the operand is `1` but not both:

`0 ^ 0 = 0`, `1 ^ 0 = 1`, `1 ^ 0 = 0` and `1 ^ 1 = 0`.

Identical numbers cancel each other as `x ^ x == 0` for all values.  The final outcome of xoring all elements of the array is the number occurring an odd number of times, assuming there is only one.

This method works if all duplicate numbers but one occur an even number of times and if there is a single entry occurring an odd number of times.

Answer (score 1):

> But I can't visualize it

Then you should step through the code one line at a time and keep an eye on `res` at each iteration through the loop.

Or just do it on paper -- write down the binary form of 12, i.e. `00001100`, and then XOR that value with the next value, also `00001100`, which gets you back to `00000000`. Then XOR the next value with that, and so on. You might want to start with a short list of pairs of numbers, like `{12, 12, 15, 15}` and see what happens. Then try removing the last one, so you have `{12, 12, 15}` and see what you get. Then try reordering the list: `{12, 15, 12}`. Count the number of times that each bit gets flipped.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about XOR operator.

`^` is bit-wise XOR.
For example,
`12^5 == 1100^0101 == (1^0)(1^1)(0^1)(0^1) == 1011`

From the mathematical definition of `XOR`, the output is `1` iif the number of `1`(s) in inputs is odd.

**This case:**
When a number occurs even number of times, the binary representation will also get two `1`s or two `0`s in each position, making the result going to `0`.

**Eg:**

```
2^2^3 == (1^1^1)(0^0^1) == 11 == 3
 i.e.   10 (2) 
        10 (2) 
        11 (3)
       --------
        11 (3)
       ========

5^7^5 == (1^1^1)(0^1^0)(1^1^1) == 111
         101 (5)
         111 (7)
         101 (5)
        ---------
         111 (7)
        =========
```

Note that even occurring numbers have no affect here.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is commutative: `a ^ b` equals `b ^ a`.
XOR is associative: `a ^ (b ^ c)` equals `(a ^ b) ^ c`.

Together these two mean that you can arbitrarily reorder operands in a chain of XORs.

Furthermore:

`0` is a neutral element: `a ^ 0` equals `a`.
Every number is its own inverse: `a ^ a` equals `0`.

---

In your code we're doing `12 ^ 12 ^ 14 ^ 90 ^ 14 ^ 14 ^ 14`.

We can reorder this to `(12 ^ 12) ^ (14 ^ 14) ^ (14 ^ 14) ^ 90`, pairing up every element that occurs an even number of times with itself.

This simplifies to `0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 90` (because all pairs of equal elements cancel each other out, giving `0`), which reduces to just `90` (because XORing with `0` does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Given the following axioms:

```
x ^ x      == 0
y ^ y ^ y  == y
z ^ 0      == z
```

Then for example:

```
x ^ x ^ y ^ y ^ y == y
\___/   \_______/
  0   ^     y     == y
```

Also:

```
x ^ y == y ^ x
```

So the order of the operands does not matter.

The point is an odd number of occurrences of a value results in the value, while even results in zero, and a value xor'ed with zero is the value.

Consequently as the comment at the start of the code suggests, it works only when there is a single value with an odd number of occurrences and all other values occur an even number of times.  Otherwise the result is simply the xor of all the odd occurring values, e.g.:

```
x ^ x ^ x ^ y == x ^ y
```

which is neither x nor y.